# Good IDE (Or VIM replacement/plugin) for code formatting over SSH (PHP or others)

Tags: php, linux, ide, formatting

I find myself having to code PHP on a remote server, and, being comparatively new at PHP, I find myself executing and testing a lot.

At this point though, I have an error in *quite* a few nested if statements that are only going to get more complex, so more formatting would be very nice indeed!

I realize this question might be a little open-ended, but I was wondering if someone would be so kind as to alert me to a solution for efficiently formatting code (in this case PHP, though all languages are welcome, especially C++) that is to be manipulated remotely.

(Seamless local-to-remote is fine as well.)

I can't even really find a way to add leading spaces or tabs in VIM.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `quite a few nested if statements that are only going to get more complex` finding an editor isn't the only problem you've got. I don't think your question is on topic for stack overflow.

Comment: You should have just asked questions about properly configuring VIM... There isnt much better if you have to do it over SSH... Well some would argue Emacs, btu theyre idiots ;-) Also... if you have super deep tree of nested `if` statements: `Youre doing it wrong.`

Comment: in vim select all (in visual mode) and then press enter

Comment: This is more of a test front for something else.  I know it may not be good practice, but I just need to rapidly develop this front-end for something... they will likely go away... I just thought I'd mention the inspiration for the question....

Comment: I do appreciate the coding advice, though :).

Comment: Or use `sshfs` and use any IDE you like...

Comment: Another option would be to selfish format the code and refactoring the nested ifs during this.  ;)

Comment: Yesss... you guys are right.  Its really annoying to look at these things.  *Will* be refactored... formatting still useful lol.

Comment: Ahh... I'll ask another question about how to configure VIM.  Thanks for the attention, though.

Comment: @Wrikken: Depending on the OS and Editor SSHFS can be super slow for editing a "project" of files. Example Textmate 1.x on OS X (though to be fair ive only tried using expandrive and macfusion sshfs mounts... not using the raw FUSE utils from the CLI.

Comment: @prodigitalson: Well, with local servers the fuse one suits me fine (allthough I should use nfs there), remote with compression on of course, but yeah... if your IDE does a lot of re-indexing or mass-edits in the background it might become sluggish indeed. Good thing I keep my editors lightweight ;)

Comment: @AD7six Hmmm.... where do you think that this question *does* belong, then.

Comment: Are you using the netrw module?